# jquery library via ender

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ender

I have tried building jquery into ender.js.

```
ender build jquery
```

The library is correctly installed, but I see many dependencies I don't need.

Is it the minimal version of jquery I can embed via ender or a version intended to be used from Node.js?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical use for ender is to replace jQuery with different ender "libraries" (qwery, bean etc). If you really want to bundle jQuery with ender, I believe it is going to give you the full version of jQuery (all features). You can always [build your own](https://github.com/jquery/jquery#what-you-need-to-build-your-own-jquery) and bundle it with Ender later on.

Comment: Thank you Nick. My mistake, because I wanted to use Ender.js simply as a build tool to merge vendor libraries into one file.

Comment: Not a problem. I'd suggest using [smoosh](https://github.com/fat/smoosh) or [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to package/minify your different plugins/libraries.